# Cumulative sum of an array using recursion in C

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I want to write a function in C `void cumsum(int *array, int length)` that receives an array as an input then changes its element of that array to the cumulative sum using RECURSION. For instance if i have `array = {1,2,3}` the output should be `array={1,3,6}`.

So, how I can do this using recursion.

Comment: What do you have so far?  This really isn't a problem to throw recursion at though ...unless this is some ill-conceived homework assignment.  This can trivially be done with a for loop and a few lines of code ...literally

Comment: I know how to do it with for loop but don't know how to do it with recursion

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you want to use recursion for this?   I only ask because not every problem makes sense to do recursively.  IMO, recursion should only be used as a last resort, when it's benefits outweigh an iterative solution (or if an iterative solution does not exist).  If you are just asking because you're trying to learn about recursion, then that's fine.  But trying to teach recursion with a problem like this will likely leave more questions then answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void cumsum(int *array, int index) {
    if(index <= 0) return;
    cumsum(array, index -1);
    array[index] += array[index - 1];
}

int main(void) {
    int array[] = {1,2,3};
    cumsum(array, 2}; //you had to call with the index of the last element (size-1)
    printf("%d %d %d\n", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean count, not size, right?

Comment: change to `if(--index <= 0) return;cumsum(array, index);` for call `cumsum(array, 3};`

Answer (score 1):

one way:

```
void cumsum(int* array, int length,int pos){
if(pos+1<length) array=cumsum(array,length,pos+1);
 for(int i=pos+1;i<length;i++){
  array[i]+=array[pos];
 }
}
```